# python beginner 2.x - re.findall() doesn't find every link i need

Tags: python

my nice CS teacher gave me sweet summer vacation work - build an automatic "the wiki game" - you give it two pages as a parameter and it finds the shortest path between the two..
anyways, i use urllib, urllib2 and re modules. so i googled "how to get all the links from html in python" or something like that and found this:

```
links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)
```

it works great for other links-everylink but wikipedia. it doesn't seem to find anything in wiki besides the current page.

the whole code of my 'project' in case you wanna check it (it's not done yet and it's not the game-im now only printing the url pages):

```
import urllib,urllib2,re

def wikiexists (_strvalue):
    errorr='Wikipedia does not'
    _strvalue= _strvalue.replace(" ","_")
    try:
        page=urllib2.urlopen(('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s') % (_strvalue,))
        return True
    except:
        return False

def openwikiurl (_string):
    _string= _string.replace(" ","_")
    page=urllib2.urlopen(('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s') % (_string,))
    return page

def DaGame (start,end,maxnum):
    if wikiexists(start)==False or wikiexists(end)==False:
        print "One of your pages doesn't exist!"
    else:
        shortest (openwikiurl(start),openwikiurl(end),0,maxnum)

def shortest (current,target,now,maxnumber):
    if now>maxnumber:
        print "sorry too many attempts"
    if current is target:
        print """The target page is found!!!
                 Shortest path: """,now
    else:

        html=current.read()
        links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)
        matches=filter (removestuff,links)
        print matches

def removestuff (tuplez):
        return True if "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" in tuplez[0] else False


DaGame ('Florida','USA',5)
```

btw in "def shortest():" i tried to print "links" and not only the filtered version of them but it also didn't give me what i wanted..

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the links on Wiki pages are relative (therefore they don't start with `http`). So you can do one of the two things: either write a regular expression that would detect all `<a href="/some/relative/url"...` elements (and fish the links from there) or use the [HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) library that can do it for you out of the box :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page source from Wikipedia you will see that the page contains relative links that redirect to pages in wikipedia. These pages do not contain https or FTP sub-strings in the link. A better mechanism would be to find all  tags using regular expressions or a parser that will look for html tags. This is quite simple and then you can rectify the true link from the reference.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(current.read())
for tag in filter(None,map(WikiTag,soup.find_all("a",href=True))):
    print tag #convert the tag into a url and do something
```

where WikiTag is something like

```
def WikiTag(link):
    if not link["href"].startswith("/wiki/"):
       return None
    tag = link["href"][6:]
    if ":" in tag:
       return None
    return tag
```